# Failed to make identity provider oauth callback, when configuring Identity Federation in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

The Keycloak is hosted inside a Docker container. The objective is to do the ideneity federation between the keyclaok(K1) and another partnering Keycloak (K2). K2 is hosted behind an SSL connection.

According to the documentation, I configure the trust store. But still, I get this following error,

```
Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
```

Im updating the standalone.xml for this purpose

[1] - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_truststore

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 4.5.0, the Keycloak Docker image uses standalone-ha.xml instead of standalone.xml by default. This is the reason why Keycloak did not recognize the new trust store. Below are the steps to configure trust store in Keycloak with docker based deployments.

**Step 1 :**

Add the following steps to the  standalone-ha.xml file.

```
        <spi name="truststore">
            <provider name="file" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                            <property name="file" value="/opt/jboss/truststore.jks"/>
                            <property name="password" value="password"/>
                            <property name="hostname-verification-policy" value="WILDCARD"/>
                            <property name="disabled" value="false"/>
                    </properties>
            </provider>
        </spi>
```

**Step 2:**

Copy the file to the docker container

```
docker cp standalone-ha.xml continer_id:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
```

**Step 3:**

Copy the certificate inside the container. The certificate can be exported from the browser itself (public certificate).

`docker cp cert.crt 9fbd81264f65:/opt/jboss/cert.crt`

**Step 4:**

ssh into the container
`docker exec -it container_id bash`

**Step 5:**

```
keytool -import -alias efactory-nimble.salzburgresearch.at -keystore truststore.jks -file cert.crt
```

**Step 6:**

docker restart `container_id`

[1] - https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-October/016066.html